# Jquery remove class is re-applying the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

I m new to jquery and I m trying to add and then remove a div class. First I add the class name with `addClass();` when clicking on the div, and then I want to remove it by clicking on a link. This is the code I wrote so far, but it is not working.
https://jsfiddle.net/j2tsk90k/1/

What am I doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="block yellow expandable skewX">
<div>Test</div> <span id="transp">  
<a id="close">close</a>
</span>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.expandable').on('click', function () {
 $(this).addClass('fullscreen');
});

$('#close').click(function () {
 $('.expandable').removeClass('fullscreen');
});
```

Note:

- On firefox it behaves like it is re-applying the class when clicking the link.
- On Chrome the link is not clickable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put the relevant code in question itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because parent event is being triggered on child click. You need to stop event propagation to child element:

```
$('#close').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  $('.expandable').removeClass('fullscreen');
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d5rakdb6/)**

Comment: Thanks, worked perfecty. I must read more. First time i saw stopPropagation(). I'll google it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `#close` is a child of `.expandable`. Therefore, when you click on `#close`, the click listener on `.expandable` is also triggered (which means that you remove the class and directly after add it back).

To solve your issue, you should make sure that your closing item isn't a child of the opening item.